# Is there a way to decrease display contrast on Mac?

Tags: display, accessibility

I know you can *increase* display contrast on Mac in Accessibility. But is there some way to decrease contrast?

Are there any third-party apps that'll do this in the case that you can't do it natively?

Comment: You could set up a low contrast display profile to switch to, but as the calibration structure isn't designed that way [it's designed for an approximation of 'accuracy'] then it might be a bit of trial & error.

Comment: @Tetsujin How would that work? I tried creating a manual Color Profile in Displays but it only let me adjust white point.

Comment: Hold Opt whilst clicking Calibrate… & it will expose an Advanced mode. I'm not sure exactly what you'd need to tweak to intentionally get less contrast & you'll probably have to balance it against Brightness to get it comfortable. You can always do a bit of trial & error & you can keep multiple versions if you like. I don't often use the built-in calibrator at all, I have a hardware colorimeter to set my displays up.

Comment: @Tetsujin I don't see that anywhere. There's no calibration button in Displays or when I go to create a new profile. It also says 'some steps may be skipped on some displays' so maybe that has something to do with it.

Comment: Not sure how you managed to create a profile without clicking Calibrate. I thought it may have moved in Big Sur, but it's still in the same place - https://i.stack.imgur.com/rC6pU.png

Comment: @Tetsujin Oh, I'm in Monterey, so it seems the menus have changed a little bit. That's why.

Comment: [This](https://osxdaily.com/2010/06/17/change-your-mac-displays-contrast/) used to work but I don't think it works now